# Why doesn't the sampling rate of the ESP32 go any higher than 10 kHz?

Tags: adc, esp32, sampling

I put this simple code in the Arduino IDE. I expect a message in the serial monitor every second saying time for 50000 readings is 1 millisecond.

```
int t1 = 0;
int t2 = 0;
int adc_read_counter = 0;
int SamplingRate = 50000; // Read 50000 values in one second.

hw_timer_t * timer = NULL; 
volatile bool interruptbool1 = false;

/*Interrupt routine for Timer overflow event*/
void IRAM_ATTR onTimer() {
  interruptbool1 = true; // Indicates that the interrupt has been entered since the last time its value was changed to false 
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true); // Begin timer with 1 MHz frequency (80MHz/80)
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &onTimer, true); // Attach the interrupt to Timer1
  unsigned int timerFactor = 1000000/SamplingRate; // Calculate the time interval between two readings, or more accurately, the number of cycles between two readings
  timerAlarmWrite(timer, timerFactor, true);      //Initialize the timer
  timerAlarmEnable(timer); 
}

void loop() {
  if (interruptbool1) {
    analogRead(36);
    interruptbool1 = false;
    if (adc_read_counter == 1) {
      t1 = millis();
    }
    if (adc_read_counter == 50001) {
      t2 = millis();
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Time taken to read 50000 readings is ");
      Serial.print(t2-t1);
      Serial.println(" milliseconds");
      Serial.println();
      adc_read_counter = 0;
    }
    adc_read_counter++;
  }
}
```

Instead of that, this happens:

[image]

No matter what I do it seems the sample rate doesn't go any higher than 10 kHz. I tried putting a higher value for the variable SamplingRate but the sampling rate never goes higher. Why does this happen?

Comment: Have you considered that `analogRead()` might simply be slow?

Comment: From the downloadable PDF datasheet: "Sampling rate RTC controller – 200 ksps, DIG controller – 2 Msps". Then, there are the "two high-resolution, high-speed ADCs" in the 2.4 GHz receiver - no idea about the extent of programmatic access.

Comment: The code could do anything really. What happens if you simply ignore all that interrupt stuff and do a minimal code that proves or disproves the assumption? Just measure how many milliseconds it takes to get 50000 samples in a for loop, and then see what is the result?

Comment: Your measured time is suspiciously "round". Are you sure that your timer is running at 80MHz and not 20MHz?

Comment: Include your counter increment inside the interrupt routine. If I remember well, a for/next loop is about 3 ms for the classic Arduino board at 16 MHz.

Comment: @JonathanS. It is because of that. I removed analogRead and i could achieve sample frequencies up to 200kHz. But once i put analogRead the sample frequency drops tremendously... Problem is in my program it will need 3 analogRead and still send info aboout those via wi-fi, so with these new things the sample frequency is no where near the one i need (48kHz)...